# C# : The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine . How to debug via network Trace

Tags: c#, iis

Our consumers are using our REST API and complaining that ~1% request are failing under error: **The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine** . They said that they tried to bypassed this error by following suggestions on stack overflow and others like

1. Set UseUnsafeHeaderParsing value to "true" in web.config
2. Set KeepAlive to "false"
3. Set Expect100Continue to "true".

but it didn't resolve the issue. To understand this issue better we created a console application to consume our API and we are also facing the same Issue and it occur for ~1% (for 100 request, only 1 will fail and the data we are fetching is same). Since the API is on HTTPS and cannot be hosted on HTTP, it is difficult to do packet capture via Wireshark (security team will not share RSA key token).

We tried to do debugging in VS-2019 and enable the diagnostics and able to capture System.Net dump. I'm also able to pin-point problematic API call but unable to understand further. It seems that something is added in HTTP header during response from server which cause WebExceptionStatus.ServerProtocolViolation in CheckValid Method of System.Net. Kindly help me to debug below logs

**1: Correct Response**

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Data from Socket#6122357::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000005 : 29 61 45 12 47 A7 AB CA-2D 8C 30 C7 7E 93 F2 6A : )aE.G...-.0.~..j
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000015 : 3A 9E 6B 89 95 87 B3 CE-16 AF F4 46 ED 6C BC F2 : :.k........F.l..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000025 : BC 59 55 D1 8B 1F F3 31-C7 48 11 9C 3C 4B FC F0 : .YU....1.H..<K..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000035 : 18 AA 7A 23 BB 58 A9 BC-F0 6F 25 2B FB 21 AA F8 : ..z#.X...o%+.!..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000045 : B1 C7 5B 5D 88 F0 69 EB-2D DD 5A 69 5A 0D 81 C2 : ..[]..i.-.ZiZ...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000055 : 59 0A 83 12 92 DC D6 9D-18 B6 AB C9 8C A9 C3 1C : Y...............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000065 : 25 AF D1 99 89 8B C6 0C-BA CC 04 85 EE CA 97 84 : %...............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000075 : 07 9F C1 4F 45 67 71 C6-2D F9 D1 9D 68 EF 63 46 : ...OEgq.-...h.cF
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000085 : 23 E1 0C 35 60 50 17 7E-4A FA E1 E6 BA 35 AF 57 : #..5`P.~J....5.W
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000095 : B7 2A 1D B1 AB 8C 86 01-8A DF 0D 4E 6B 30 72 0C : .*.........Nk0r.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000A5 : 27 A5 D2 80 8E 29 E6 14-AD AE 32 47 B8 25 25 4A : '....)....2G.%%J
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000B5 : 42 FA 99 0A DF 1F 59 EB-1B CB 6C 36 5F BB D8 F6 : B.....Y...l6_...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000C5 : E4 9D 73 7E 3B 0D 97 E1-0B 23 0E 16 4D 78 6B 91 : ..s~;....#..Mxk.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000D5 : 5B A1 22 83 76 D4 76 CF-99 05 20 1A 71 C5 4C A5 : [.".v.v... .q.L.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000E5 : 2D BB DD B0 2C AE F7 19-15 FF 93 78 BF 3E 08 B6 : -...,......x.>..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000F5 : 22 26 B2 81 7C 1B DF C1-DA 0C 10 55 71 87 6A 1E : "&..|......Uq.j.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000105 : AA AA 0C 4C 49 62 AE 45-3F 70 53 35 F5 C9 3A A3 : ...LIb.E?pS5..:.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000115 : FA B6 0F EC 30 52 D7 E1-E0 00 C2 41 B3 8D 7F AB : ....0R.....A....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000125 : B4 50 B7 08 C0 7B 96 ED-AF 64 55 D9 84 FB FF 95 : .P...{...dU.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000135 : E2 B3 3A 0C A1 AA 23 C9-DD A8 8D F5 C0 0D FA 9F : ..:...#.........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000145 : A5 8E BD F4 B9 66 0E 60-F1 20 93 B1 8A 81 4F D9 : .....f.`. ....O.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000155 : D5 AB 36 D9 85 CD 7D B6-DF F9 34 64 1A 12 B9 0B : ..6...}...4d....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000165 : 36 66 AC CB 11 5A 78 DF-FF 54 3B 21 E3 0E 94 83 : 6f...Zx..T;!....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000175 : 4F 09 51 F5 1A 67 F9 5A-16 97 71 DD 98 18 A2 BD : O.Q..g.Z..q.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000185 : 40 7F DB 23 71 DC B0 8B-F6 D4 A1 2D 2B F8 8E 1E : @..#q......-+...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting Socket#6122357::Receive()   -> Int32#400
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] Connection#60332585 - Received status line: Version=1.1, StatusCode=200, StatusDescription=OK.
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] Connection#60332585 - Received headers
{
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Pragma: no-cache
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 
Content-Length: 226
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 20 Feb 2020 16:01:24 GMT
Expires: -1
Server: 
X-Powered-By: 
}.
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] ConnectStream#24230272::ConnectStream(Buffered 226 bytes.)
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] Associating HttpWebRequest#53517805 with ConnectStream#24230272
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] Associating HttpWebRequest#53517805 with HttpWebResponse#16745860
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting HttpWebRequest#53517805::GetResponse()  -> HttpWebResponse#16745860
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Entering HttpWebResponse#16745860::GetResponseStream()
System.Net Information: 0 : [25884] ContentLength=226
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting HttpWebResponse#16745860::GetResponseStream()   -> ConnectStream#24230272
```

**2: Incorrect response**

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Entering Socket#6122357::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Data from Socket#6122357::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000005 : 63 FC 57 65 D8 01 9E F0-4A 55 72 04 80 CF 8A 82 : c.We....JUr.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000015 : A7 63 84 74 04 74 F3 F7-8D AE 64 C7 AE C3 90 59 : .c.t.t....d....Y
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000025 : F4 B2 53 51 E7 8F 9D 69-CF 6A EC 00 D8 AE 1D E8 : ..SQ...i.j......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000035 : 5B D1 11 96 2E 78 86 6C-D0 2A 82 88 F2 FE 6F 06 : [....x.l.*....o.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000045 : 68 CD F7 EC 62 79 D4 07-73 78 90 6B 36 DF 89 BF : h...by..sx.k6...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000055 : 3C B0 18 AC 94 08 F8 35-72 69 E9 F4 A1 6F 3F 21 : <......5ri...o?!
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000065 : 04 EF 45 09 C3 48 AA 14-8C A4 C1 01 1D 1D CD 79 : ..E..H.........y
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000075 : 2C B7 71 4D AC 6B D8 4C-E8 A9 39 7D BC 25 39 29 : ,.qM.k.L..9}.%9)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000085 : 6B 67 C0 83 61 9C BC 2D-CF 58 31 B6 DE 76 3B 6E : kg..a..-.X1..v;n
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000095 : E0 A1 86 25 D2 72 BB 00-D1 5F 08 AB 2E 75 2A 71 : ...%.r..._...u*q
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000A5 : 00 5F 57 34 48 95 0A 93-9D 1C 50 76 9D 87 2F 2A : ._W4H.....Pv../*
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000B5 : A1 D3 AE 19 F0 24 1F B0-BA 18 BE F8 18 EF 3F 1C : .....$........?.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000C5 : B2 4C 99 CB 98 5B 7D 3F-77 57 0E A2 74 35 7B 2A : .L...[}?wW..t5{*
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000D5 : BA 01 A3 B2 AE C6 A7 D2-7F BE 5C BD 1A 81 1A DA : ..........\.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000E5 : 0E D4 D8 62 CF 6C D0 9E-A4 64 97 65 CE B4 55 12 : ...b.l...d.e..U.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000000F5 : 6B 44 35 62 F5 A9 35 F0-9B 64 28 00 68 40 CE FC : kD5b..5..d(.h@..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000105 : CD 5C FB 2B BE 77 E4 D7-DB 98 30 19 8F A7 FE B6 : .\.+.w....0.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000115 : EC AB DC 4F B6 D0 B7 72-5D 44 58 B0 43 DF 5E 62 : ...O...r]DX.C.^b
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000125 : 3B C3 FB 1D C4 29 07 DF-48 51 B1 F5 BA DB C3 C1 : ;....)..HQ......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000135 : 75 6D 01 8A 5D 27 1F 88-26 67 35 1E 7B 3E 70 C6 : um..]'..&g5.{>p.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000145 : 5E 38 AD 56 95 E2 49 E2-87 0B 2E 7D 8E 66 39 20 : ^8.V..I....}.f9 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000155 : 05 47 08 17 28 40 97 4F-2C 56 C7 B5 CA 3E 09 D9 : .G..(@.O,V...>..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000165 : D6 EA 62 65 20 CA EB 7F-43 70 1E 0A 2D 1A 00 E9 : ..be ...Cp..-...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000175 : 81 4A EB 8A 6E FE F2 C1-AC EC 24 0D 24 13 A5 7D : .J..n.....$.$..}
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000185 : 7D 0E D2 CF 25 C6 E2 6B-0C 28 56 5D C3 E3 32 92 : }...%..k.(V]..2.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 00000195 : 85 33 D8 59 80 4D AE 5A-B3 47 CF E1 53 47 2C A5 : .3.Y.M.Z.G..SG,.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] 000001A5 : 30 EA 1D 68 92 65 5A 75-B5 AA A5 87 B8 D5 BC 0A : 0..h.eZu........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting Socket#6122357::Receive()   -> Int32#432
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [25884] Entering Socket#6122357::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [25884] Exception in HttpWebRequest#4152081:: - The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.
System.Net Error: 0 : [25884] Exception in HttpWebRequest#4152081::GetResponse - The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine.
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Entering WebRequest::Create(https://[ myDomain.com] /xyz/abc/ConfirmPayment)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Entering HttpWebRequest#6968762::HttpWebRequest(https:// [myDomain.com] /xyz/abc/ConfirmPayment#-1194737012)
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting HttpWebRequest#6968762::HttpWebRequest() 
System.Net Verbose: 0 : [25884] Exiting WebRequest::Create()    -> HttpWebRequest#6968762
```

If you need any other data, please tell. Kindly guide me in right direction

**25-Feb-2020** @Vaptarov please find Fiddler packet capture. Kindly guide.

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Fiddler - Bad Response
Date: Tue, 25 Feb 2020 14:28:21 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Timestamp: 19:58:21.837

[Fiddler] Response Header parsing failed.
This can be caused by an illegal HTTP response earlier on this reused server socket-- for instance, a HTTP/304 response which illegally contains a body.
Response Data:
<plaintext>
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A  ........................
0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 0D 0A 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 32 30 30  ............HTTP/1.1 200
20 4F 4B 0D 0A 58 2D 46 72 61 6D 65 2D 4F 70 74 69 6F 6E 73 3A 20 53 41   OK..X-Frame-Options: SA
4D 45 4F 52 49 47 49 4E 0D 0A 43 61 63 68 65 2D 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 3A  MEORIGIN..Cache-Control:
20 6E 6F 2D 63 61 63 68 65 0D 0A 50 72 61 67 6D 61 3A 20 6E 6F 2D 63 61   no-cache..Pragma: no-ca
63 68 65 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 4C 65 6E 67 74 68 3A 20 32 32 36  che..Content-Length: 226
0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69 63 61 74  ..Content-Type: applicat
69 6F 6E 2F 6A 73 6F 6E 3B 20 63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3D 75 74 66 2D 38 0D  ion/json; charset=utf-8.
0A 45 78 70 69 72 65 73 3A 20 2D 31 0D 0A 58 2D 58 53 53 2D 50 72 6F 74  .Expires: -1..X-XSS-Prot
65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 31 3B 20 6D 6F 64 65 3D 62 6C 6F 63 6B 0D 0A 58  ection: 1; mode=block..X
2D 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 2D 4F 70 74 69 6F 6E 73 3A 20 6E  -Content-Type-Options: n
6F 73 6E 69 66 66 0D 0A 53 74 72 69 63 74 2D 54 72 61 6E 73 70 6F 72 74  osniff..Strict-Transport
2D 53 65 63 75 72 69 74 79 3A 20 6D 61 78 2D 61 67 65 3D 33 31 35 33 36  -Security: max-age=31536
30 30 30 0D 0A 53 45 52 56 45 52 3A 20 0D 0A 58 2D 50 4F 57 45 52 45 44  000..SERVER: ..X-POWERED
2D 42 59 3A 20 0D 0A 58 2D 41 73 70 4E 65 74 4D 76 63 2D 56 65 72 73 69  -BY: ..X-AspNetMvc-Versi
6F 6E 3A 20 0D 0A 44 61 74 65 3A 20 54 75 65 2C 20 32 35 20 46 65 62 20  on: ..Date: Tue, 25 Feb 
32 30 32 30 20 31 34 3A 32 37 3A 34 32 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 0D 0A           2020 14:27:42 GMT....
```

Comment: First, disable HTTPS. Second, use Wireshark to capture and analyze HTTP traffic.

Comment: I can't disable HTTPS as this API is in production and capture consumer payment. In our QA environment, it didn't show this error and the setting of QA and Prod API land scape is same (Firewall/Load balancer/IIS setting are all same). Is this error somehow related to load?

Comment: Use Fiddler as it can decrypt the HTTPS traffic that goes from the pc on which it is run and target your prod with a testing account, do the same steps to reproduce your issue. 

It may help you find what is going on ?

Comment: @saurabhsharma same issue for me. Do you find why this issue is occurring and any solution?